# Securing stored procedure and stored functions

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, stored-functions

I have more than a few stored procedures and user-defined functions, both available in SQL Server and HANA Server.

I am currently looking for ways to apply security on the stored procedures and UDFs, ways to prevent someone on altering them.

I have done research about using the `WITH ENCRYPTION` clause, but later on realized it has more disadvantages than advantages and opted out of the option.

Are there any other methods to secure them?

Comment: If you only grant `EXECUTE` privilege (or whatever the equivalent in HANA and SQL Server is) then the users can't alter them.

Comment: Thank you. The servers are on premise meaning the users are the ones who set them up, granting roles might be a problem. Unless I don't quite get the aspect of grant feature